# Laravel 4 custom validation function , not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to have my own simple custom validation function

Here is my code :

```
    $rules = array(
                    'first_name'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
                    'last_name'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
                    'email'=>'sometimes',
                    'password'=>'alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
                    'password_confirmation'=>'alpha_num|between:6,12'
                    );
                    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
                    $input = Input::all();
                    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules ); 
                    $validator->sometimes('email', 'required|email', function($input)
                    {
                            // get user info from db 
                          $user = User::find(Input::get('id'));

                      if (Input::get('email') != $user->email)
                         {
                            // find that email in the database 
                             $foundemail = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=' ,Input::get('email'))->get();
                            if(!empty($foundemail))
                             return false;


                          }
                          else
                          {
                            return true;

                          }
                  });
```

how do I add a custom message to this , basically I need to check for email field:
1). required
2). email
3). if email edited is the same as the one if the database , then continue with the edit. if email is different I need to check inputed email if it is in the database and show an error

how could I do that please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides built-in rule to check whether value is unique in database or not, please check this out: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

Comment: yes I know but the problem I am doing an edit not an add new , if I use unique:users,email , it will check that is the user is not unique and it gives me an error how to by pass that?

Comment: You mean you'd like to check if it's unique, but between all records except the one that is edited? So if you edit record with ID = 5, it should check if the email is unique where ID != 5?

Comment: I tried this 'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email', and I get and error message saying my email is taken , but I am doing an update to that email

Comment: yes exactly how can I do that , if its unique except the one I am editing , basically its for an eidt user

Comment: `unique` rule provides that, please read carefully all use cases in the link I provided :)

Comment: thanks alot figured it out , it would be easier if you provides some code :)

Comment: Are you able to use this example to satisfy your needs?

Comment: this what I did : 'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Input::get('id').',id'

Comment: I believe you can skip `,id` part, as `id` is default field name.

Comment: really maybe :) , could you help me with pagination? no one in stckoverfloow could solve it maybe you could

Comment: referring to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072493/laravel-4-pagination-and-sort-header